# I have issues with clearTimeout(), it's not clearing anything

Tags: javascript, timeout, cleartimeout

I'm trying to make a nice confirm page with a fingerprint design, I added colors to it for it when you hover the fingerprint to "load", if you took the mouse off the fingerprint it will go red as failed and if you hold it for 2 seconds it will show green, my issue is the timer, if I quickly hover the svg and then remove the mouse it will run the function.

I tried to move the loading var outside the functions, it didn't work. I tried to put it inside a ready(), still doesn't work.

Update: I tried to debug, looks like the `if($('.fingerprint').hasClass('approved') === "false")` doesn't work, even though I did console.log and it shows it's false...

Update 2: Fixed! Seems like hasClass is not a string, I just removed the "" and it worked.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

    $("#fingerprint").hover(
    function () {
        var loading; 
        $('.fingerprint').find('*').removeClass('declined');
        $('.fingerprint').find('*').addClass('loading');
        loading = setTimeout(function approved() {
            console.log("Done");
            $('.fingerprint').find('*').removeClass('loading');
            $('.fingerprint').find('*').addClass('approved');
        }, 2000);
    },
    function () {
        var loading;
        if($('.fingerprint').hasClass('approved') === "false") {
        $('.fingerprint').find('*').removeClass('loading');
        $('.fingerprint').find('*').addClass('declined');
        clearTimeout(loading);
        }
    });
});
```

I expect the color to not switch green after the 2 seconds unless you hovered your mouse on the SVG, I have no errors but the clearTimeout() clearly doesn't work.

Comment: `var loading` is defined twice; bring the declaration out to the main function. You may need to read about hoisting(https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-hoisting-in-javascript)

Comment: I see that's not the issue now, the if doesn't work